# Multiple rows out of a single record

Tags: sql, postgresql

lets say that e.g if i did `SELECT * FROM X` i'd get

```
A1, A2, A3, A4, A5, A6, A7
```

is it possible to do a query that for each record returns

```
A1, A2, A3    
A1, A2, A4
A1, A2, A5
A1, A2, A6
A1, A2, A7
```

????

My actual problem ( and this is just additional information, not required to answer the question ) --> i have a db about football matches so i have players etc but the table **matches** are like this:

```
homeplayer1 (fk)
homeplayer2 (fk)
.
.
.
homeplayerN (fk)
```

and same for away players but i'm working on a multidimiensional db implementation that requires to have only one player associated per match so it'd be 22 records per match to fit the 22 players.

I'm using postgresql.

Comment: SQL tables are inherently unordered.  Please provide information on how the ordering in the table is defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 select a1, a2,
        unnest(array[a3,a4,a5,a6,a7])
   from X
```

Test on [sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/0a28f/35)

Comment: Is it possible to match the unnested rows with two other rows? something like: unnest(array[a3 with a8,a4 with a8, a5 with a8,a6 with a9,a7 with a9])

Comment: @AlejandroCamba understood nothing. give an example of the complete data and the expected result

Comment: Oh, the values are multiple columns in a single row.  Duh.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume that some column defines the ordering; I'll call it `ord`:

```
with t as (
      select x.*, row_number() over (order by ord) as seqnum
      from x
     )
select t1.col, t2.col, t3.col
from t t1 join
     t t2
     on t1.seqnum = 1 and t2.seqnum = 2 join
     t t3
     on t3.seqnum > 2;
```

You may want to ask *another* question about your actual problem, which looks a bit different from what you asked in this question.

Comment: No this is great i'll try it in a sec